# Craft Commerce 3 + Stripe for Craft Commerce, error while attempting to pay with iDEAL

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, plugin-commerce-stripe

I'm using headless Craft CMS + Craft Commerce 3 + Stripe for Craft Commerce plugin to create the webshop. My frontend is decoupled and built in Nuxt.js.

I need to implement the payment form with the iDEAL payment method.

I'm getting the following error when trying to submit the payment form from the frontend `"The PaymentMethod provided (ideal) is not allowed for this PaymentIntent. Please attach a PaymentMethod of one of the following types: card. Alternatively, update the allowed payment_method_types for this PaymentIntent to include "ideal"."`

Can you please tell me what is the issue here ?

my code for the frontend:

```
  // Create a Stripe client.
  const stripe = await loadStripe(
    'pk_test_***'
  )
  // Create an instance of Elements.
  const elements = stripe.elements()

  const options = {
    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    style: {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4',
        },
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a',
      },
    },
  }

  // Create an instance of the iDEAL Element.
  const idealBank = elements.create('idealBank', options)

  // Add an instance of the idealBank Element into
  // the `ideal-bank-element` <div>.
  idealBank.mount('#ideal-bank-element')

  idealBank.on('change', function (event) {
    const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors')
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = ''
    }
  })

  // Create a source or display an error when the form is submitted.
  const form = document.getElementById('payment_form')

  form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const paymentData = {
      billing_details: {
        email: this.customerEmail,
      },
    }

    console.log('payment data', paymentData)

    // https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method
    stripe
      .createPaymentMethod('ideal', idealBank, paymentData)
      .then(async (result) => {
        if (result.error) {
          // Inform the user if there was an error.
          const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors')
          errorElement.textContent = result.error.message
        } else {
          // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
          const form = document.getElementById('payment_form')
          const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input')
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'paymentMethodId') // This is the only thing that needs to be submitted to the craft server.
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', result.paymentMethod.id)
          form.appendChild(hiddenInput)

          const inputs = document.getElementById('payment_form').elements
         
          const payload = {       
            email: inputs.namedItem('email').value,
            gatewayId: inputs.namedItem('gatewayId').value,
            paymentMethodId: inputs.namedItem('paymentMethodId').value, 
          }

          const paymentMethodResponse = await this.$store.dispatch(
            'cart/pay',
            payload
          )

          ...
        }
      })
},
```

my craft gateway configuration:
[image]